# Regex split file between substring

Tags: regex, matlab, split, substring

I have a CSV file with data from multiple variables, and I would like to separate them. My file looks like this:

```
VARIABLE: GRP1.SGRP1.100:VAR1

Timestamp (LOCAL_TIME),Value
2018-07-18 13:52:09.100,25582
2018-07-18 13:52:49.900,24048
VARIABLE: GRP1.SGRP2.102:VAR1

Timestamp (LOCAL_TIME),Value
2018-07-18 13:52:09.100,25582
2018-07-18 13:52:49.900,24048
```

And I would like to split it on every occurrence of the substring "VARIABLE", producing two strings:

```
VARIABLE: GRP1.SGRP1.100:VAR1

Timestamp (LOCAL_TIME),Value
2018-07-18 13:52:09.100,25582
2018-07-18 13:52:49.900,24048
```

and

```
VARIABLE: GRP1.SGRP2.102:VAR1

Timestamp (LOCAL_TIME),Value
2018-07-18 13:52:09.100,25582
2018-07-18 13:52:49.900,24048
```

Something similar to `VARIABLE[^V]+` would seem to work, but it should somehow terminate on the next occurrence, which I cannot figure out how.
Thanks

Comment: Try `splitStr = regexp(str,'(?!^)(?=VARIABLE)','split')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Didn't work, placed everything on a single string

Comment: I don't know Matlab, but you probably need to use the single line flag in order for this to work.

Comment: Then try `matchStr = regexp(str,'VARIABLE[^V]*(?:V(?!ARIABLE)[^V]*)*','match')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, oh regex saint

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed `.` in [Matlab regex](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) *matches every character, including the newline*. There is no such a thing like *single line flag* there.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Perhaps it didn't work because of the _default_ `noemptymatch` option then?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed True, I will add that to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use two approaches, matching and splitting.

Splitting is an easier approach, since the pattern will look like `(?!^)(?=VARIABLE)`, but there is one caveat: [Matlab regex](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) expects non-empty matches by default (`noemptymatch` option is default). You need to pass the `emptymatch` option to `regexp` function for it to work:

```
splitStr = regexp(str,'\s*(?!^)(?=VARIABLE)','split', 'emptymatch')
```

Output:

```
splitStr = 
{
  [1,1] = VARIABLE: GRP1.SGRP1.100:VAR1

Timestamp (LOCAL_TIME),Value
2018-07-18 13:52:09.100,25582
2018-07-18 13:52:49.900,24048

  [1,2] = VARIABLE: GRP1.SGRP2.102:VAR1


Timestamp (LOCAL_TIME),Value
2018-07-18 13:52:09.100,25582
2018-07-18 13:52:49.900,24048
}
```

The `(?!^)(?=VARIABLE)` pattern matches any location in string that is not at the start of the string but that is immediately followed with a `VARIABLE` substring.

Alternatively, you may match `VARIABLE` and then any amount of non-`V`s or `V`s that are not followed with `ARIBALE`:

```
matchStr = regexp(str,'VARIABLE[^V]*(?:V(?!ARIABLE)[^V]*)*','match')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/naubvW/1).

**Details**

- `VARIABLE` - a `VARIABLE` substring
- `[^V]*` - a negated character class matching 0 or more chars other thatn `V`
- `(?:V(?!ARIABLE)[^V]*)*` - zero or more consecutive occurrences of

  - `V` - a `V` char that is
  - `(?!ARIABLE)` -  ... not followed with `ARIABLE`
  - `[^V]*` - 0 or more chars other than `V`.

Note it is "lexically" the same as [`VARIABLE(?:(?!VARIABLE).)*`](https://regex101.com/r/naubvW/2) (with a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat)) or [`VARIABLE.*?(?=VARIABLE|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/naubvW/3) (with lazy dot pattern and a mere positive lookahead), but is more efficient since it follows the [unroll the loop principle](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop). (Note that `.` in Matlab regex matches any char including newlines, so no need to use any additional flags when using these two patterns in Matlab).